# AngularJS: Partial view not rendering

Tags: angularjs, partial-views, angular-routing, angularjs-routing

I am trying to load partial views in a single page application using angular. I have configured the routes as shown in my script file code below.
Following is my code for loading partial views:

```
var app = angular.module("myBlogApp", ["ngRoute"])
   .config(function ($routeProvider) {
       $routeProvider
       .when("/view1", {
           templateUrl: "Views/view1.html",
           controller: "view1Controller"
       })
      .when("/view2", {
          templateUrl: "Views/view2.html",
          controller: "view2Controller"
      })
       .when("/view3", {
           templateUrl: "Views/view3.html",
           controller: "view3Controller"
       })
   })
    .controller("view1Controller", function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "You are in View 1";
    })
    .controller("view2Controller", function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "You are in View 2";
    })
    .controller("view3Controller", function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "You are in View 3";
    })
```

Following is the Index page:

```
<html ng-app="myBlogApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#/view1">View1</a>
                <a href="#/view2">View2</a>
                <a href="#/view3">View3</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div ng-view></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I load the index.html page and click on the hyperlinks, I do not see the view on my page.

The HTML on view is:

```
<h1>View2</h1>
<div>{{message}}</div>
```

Comment: do the views have `message` binding in them?

Comment: yes. Here is how the views are:
<h1>View2</h1>
<div>{{message}}</div>

Comment: what angularjs version are you using? you might need `href="#!/view1"` instead of `href="#/view1"`. Also check console.log for errors (maybe you got your path wrong)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey yes, this solved the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @Lee you can also try using `ng-href`, I think you don't need to add  `#!` there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AngularJS version 1.6 they changed the hash-prefix for URL hash-bang. Links now have `#!` instead of `#`. More about it: [commit-aa077e8](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8)

---

To remove the hash-prefix (`!`), you would need your config to have this code:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

Comment: Used #!view1 instead of #!/view1 (omitting the slash ). This also worked. Any particular reason?

Comment: @Lee don't know, but maybe it depends on how `$routeProvider.when()` works (because it ignores `/` for whatever reason)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">


<a href="#!view1">View 1</a>
<a href="#!view2">View 2</a>
<a href="#!view3">View 3</a>


<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/view1", {
        template : "{{message}}",
        controller : "view1Controller"
    })
    .when("/view2", {
        template : "{{message}}",
        controller : "view2Controller"
    })
    .when("/view3", {
        template : "{{message}}",
        controller : "view3Controller"
    });
});
app.controller("view1Controller", function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "You are in View 1";
});
app.controller("view2Controller", function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "You are in View 2";
});
app.controller("view3Controller", function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "You are in View 3";
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```